# How can I symbolize the following surface?

Tags: general-topology, geometry

I am working off of a sketch of mine included in this post, and would like to know how I could go about formalizing it using either a function, polynomial, or set.  I prefer the answer to be in polynomial form if possible.

My current thoughts are to construct it in Geogebra to see what equation it generates, or center it about an origin equal to (0, 0, 0) and attempt to apply some metric to derive a function.  Any help is appreciated.

EDIT: NOTE I am more interested in the method than the solution for this given surface.

(Please ignore the $S^3$ in the picture.)

[image: pseudotop]

Comment: You could say it's the graph with vertex set $V=\{A,B,C,D,E\}$ and edge set $E=\{AB,AC,AD,AF,BC,BD,BE,CE,CF,DE,DF,EF\}$. I think this is nearly as "formal" as you can make it.

Comment: Also, may I ask why you need to do this? What's wrong with just the picture?

Comment: even if I add information such as size of the angles?  That formalization isn't nearly close to what I'd hope it to be.  Half of it is a top, while the other is essentially a hyperbolic octahedron.  There are things I need to compute, such as a homeomorphism of this surface to another topological space.

Comment: The outer "square" looks like an asteroid. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Astroid

Comment: @CyclotomicField Thank you, this is very helpful.  Following the links revealed the deltoid, which is perfect for what I need.

Comment: @CyclotomicField If you share your finding as an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: I think that an interesting surface is provided by Cassini's ovals contour lines. I am going to provide such a representation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a proposition:

[image]

*Fig. 1: Lateral view of the surface, materialized by its level lines (contours).*

[image]

*Fig. 2: The surface seen from above.*

For explanations about cassinian ovals and their representation see [this](http://www.theochem.ru.nl/%7Epwormer/Knowino/knowino.org/wiki/Cassini_oval.html).

Matlab program:

> ```
> % Foci of cassinian ovals: E(-1,0), F(1,0), with b:=ME.MF
> clear all;close all; hold on;box on
> set(gcf,'color','w');axis([-3,3,-3,3,0,3]);
> t=0:0.01:2*pi;
> xlabel('x');ylabel('y');zlabel('z');
> t=0:0.01:pi;
> % this loops deals with level lines below the saddle point:
> for h=0:0.1:1.9; %h=height ;
>     b=3-h;
>     d=cos(2*t).^2+b^4-1;
>     r=sqrt(cos(2*t)+sqrt(d));
>     % barycentric combination between deltoid and ovals:
>     x=r.*((2-h)*cos(t).^3+h*cos(t))/2;view([170,70]);
>     y=r.*((2-h)*sin(t).^3+h*sin(t))/2;
>     z=h*ones(1,length(t))
>     plot3(x,y,z);
>     plot3(-x,-y,z);
> end;
> % This loops begins at the lemniscate (saddle point):
> for h=2:0.1:3
>     b=3-h;
>     x=sqrt(1-b^2):0.001:sqrt(1+b^2);
>     y=sqrt(-(x.^2+1)+sqrt(4*x.^2+b^4));
>     z=h*ones(1,length(x));
>     plot3(x,y,z);plot3(x,-y,z);plot3(-x,y,z);plot3(-x,-y,z);
> end
> ```

Comment: 5 minutes after having posted this answer, I just understand that you want a deltoid instead of an astroid as the basis of your surface (I was surely influenced by the comment of Cyclotomic field). But the main idea is there: combine in a barycentrical way two surfaces until you reach the lemniscate level, then proceed for the "peak areas" without barycentrical combination.

Comment: couldn't one extend this into the intersection of four deltoid though?

Comment: I just remembered an [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3467924) of mine hopefully closer to what you want...

Comment: That is indeed closer!  If you slice it in half along the vertical axis and glue half of a top to it so it has a section of a circle about the horizontal axis opposite the deltoid, that's the exact shape I'm studying.